# Virtual folder combining a read-only and read-write directory (file deduplication)

Tags: linux, merge, deduplication

Is it possible in linux to have a directory that contains all the contents of another directory (in a read-only fashion) but you are able to write to the directory without it affecting the 'parent' directory.

To provide some context of what I am trying to achieve, I have an application that will be running for all users. This application downloads several "packages" into the folder which I wish to have this functionality for. The packages each have their own unique folder (which is a hash of the contents so should be unique per package - but lets assume that hash collision is avoided with software). However, there are many packages, I know that all users will want to add and some which they will all need. If each user fills their directory with the same packages, over and over this is going to unnessarily consume space particularly with base packages that i know every user will have.

The way I see it is that when the user writes a file you can either write to the folder but when reading from the folder it merges with the parent folder OR the user can have a virtual folder of some sort that combines a read-only and read-write directory with writes automatically going to the read-write directory (I suppose somewhat similar to Windows 7 style Libraries).

The other option I can think of is completely different from my initial request but would work just as well, maybe even better as it wouldn't require me to manually work out which packages will overlap between users, would be if there is a filesystem that could be used that can provide deduplication. There are however performance problems I can see with this though - but if you have any ideas or resources you can refer me to that can do this, I will take a look. I am not sure how this would work, because I know that if a requested folder is of the same name then it doesn't need to be downloaded, but with deduplication, it would need to download the package for itself to then de-duplicate itself.

Is this possible in linux and if so what resources can you provide for me to look into the options?

Comment: Deduplication would generally be easier if you just set up the folder on a SAN which did deduplication. No need for complicated permissioning, version control, or folder moving to keep things stored in the smallest possible space.

Answer (score 1):

If your distribution includes btrfs, and if you consider it to be production-ready, you could use btrfs seed partitions.

> Seed devices. Create a (readonly) filesystem that acts as a template to seed other Btrfs filesystems. The original filesystem and devices are included as a readonly starting point for the new filesystem. Using copy on write, all modifications are stored on different devices; the original is unchanged.

Examples can be found on the [btrfs wiki page for seeds](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Seed-device)

Comment: Looks perfect from what I can see, going to do a bit of research before I give it a test in a development environment. Also seems like there are some deduping tools for btrfs which will provide both of the things I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

[UnionFS](http://unionfs.filesystems.org/) can do this with whatever underlying filesystems you want. I understand it's also included in many distributions.