# rsnapshot: how to remove all files from a tree including read-only directories

Tags: unix, permissions, rsnapshot

I just discovered that `rm -f` can not remove files from a tree including read-only directories. Is there an alternative command that can do this? The removal is triggered by rnapshot and I thought about providing a different value for "cmd_rm".

The background: I'm using `rnapshot` which emits lots of errors "permission denied" when removing the folder _delete.XXXXX. The errors occur exactly on files in read-only directories. These directory were created automatically by git-annex, so I can not simply give them write permissions.

Example:

Set up two files with different write-permissions in a read-only directory:

```
$ mkdir mydir
$ touch mydir/test1
$ touch mydir/test2
$ chmod a-w mydir/test1 
$ chmod a-w mydir/
```

Try to remove the stuff:

```
$ rm -r mydir/
rm: descend into write-protected directory ‘mydir’? y
rm: remove write-protected regular empty file ‘mydir/test1’? y
rm: cannot remove ‘mydir/test1’: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove ‘mydir/test2’: Permission denied
```

I can not even remove the files directly:

```
$ rm -rf mydir/test2
rm: cannot remove ‘mydir/test2’: Permission denied
```

Searching for the read-only directories and making them writable before removal works:

```
(find /path/to/remove -type d -not -writable | xargs chmod u+w) && rm -rf /path/to/remove
```

But the command seems really involved for a rather simple task. It this really the only solution? An how can I tell rsnapshot to do such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment so I am writing here.

As far as I know read only means read only - period. Not read write.

I guess you would have to mount your directory read write.

Comment: The filesystem mount is read-write. It is just some directory deeply in a tree which are read-only.

Comment: in that case, check out [this](http://superuser.com/questions/830712/virtual-folder-combining-a-read-only-and-read-write-directory-file-deduplicatio)

Comment: I don't have the option to change anything in the filesystem. The question is not about nested filesystems but a simple directory tree(a copy of my home directory).

Comment: then read only is read only.